# android- how to exclude a gradle library using pre defined settings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've included a library to my application , it worked fine with old sdk and google play service version but since I've updated the sdk and other libraries, it doesn't build the apk file and returns this error :

```
  Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzoj] (with 2 known super classes) and [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzol] (with 2 known super classes)
```

I've spend 2 whole days for solving this issue but I could do much , I just have to remove the library to able making the apk file .

I need to use the library .

I think I just need to exclude the google play services from this library .

how can I do so ?

Comment: are you using proguard?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel yes I do

Comment: then your google play services Ads and Base lib causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 option to solve this:

1. Disable Proguard in project
2. Remove Play services Base Lib from gradle
3. If you want to use play-base lib and enable proguard then apply
   this in proguard     and rebuild project

   -optimizations !code/allocation/variable